# How to rename an OpenSearch domain (Elasticsearch cluster on AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

The [Amazon OpenSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/createupdatedomains.html) web console provides the option to **Edit Cluster configuration**, but there is no explicit way of changing a domain's name. Is there an alternative way (such as CLI or a classic web console hidden  feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. The current choice is laborious:

1. create a new domain with the desired new name
2. restore a snapshot from the old into the new one
3. test it
4. retire/delete the old one.

Hopefully AWS may add this feature in the future or the option to add a unique alias the cluster name.